# prop with clist : prop_get returns clist, prop_map_inline does not?

Tags: l3prop, l3clist

I am sure I am missing something trivial (still learning about LaTeX3), but this seems odd: prop_map_inline does not return values as clist, even though they are?

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\prop_new:N \someProp

% put some data into prop:
\clist_set:Nn \l_tmpa_cl {a,b,c}
\clist_use:Nn \l_tmpa_cl {\ ---\ }
\prop_put:NnV \someProp {keyA} {\l_tmpa_cl}
\par

\clist_set:Nn \l_tmpa_cl {u,v,w,x,y,z}
\clist_use:Nn \l_tmpa_cl {\ ---\ }
\prop_put:NnV \someProp {keyB} {\l_tmpa_cl}
\par

% Direct access works fine; I get back a clist:
\prop_get:NnN \someProp {keyA} \l_tmpb_cl
\clist_use:Nn \l_tmpb_cl {\ ---\ }
\par 

% When iterating over property, value is no longer
% a clist, but just a string? 
\prop_map_inline:Nn \someProp { Key\ #1; \ 
  Values\ list:\ \clist_use:Nn #2 {\ ---\ } 
  \par } 

\prop_log:N \someProp

\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}
```

log file:

```
The property list \someProp contains the pairs (without outer braces):
>  {keyA}  =>  {a,b,c}
>  {keyB}  =>  {u,v,w,x,y,z}.
```

which seems as it should be. ??

Comment: you need `\clist_use:nn {#2} {\ ---\ } `  (with two small n), not `\clist_use:Nn`. And please stick to the naming scheme. It should be `\l_tmpa_clist`, and `\prop_new:N \l_karl_some_prop`. One main point of expl3 is to make code more readable by following conventions.

Comment: That works, thanks (have to mediate on WHY it works... :-). Convention: definitely; it just hard to get used to them / find useful examples.

Comment: @HolgerKarl you don't store an `N`-type into your property list, but an `n`-type (because `V` turns an `N`-type into its `n`-type representation), hence after retrieving the prop-contents you can't interpret them as `N`-type. The fact that `\prop_get:NnN` works is just per implementation detail, your code shouldn't rely on that (`\prop_get:NnN` doesn't get a `clist`, but a `tl`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `\clist_use:nn` as `#2` is not a variable (like `\l_tmpa_clist`), but simply a list of tokens (`a,b,c`).

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\prop_new:N \l_karl_some_prop

% put some data into prop:
\clist_set:Nn \l_tmpa_clist {a,b,c}
\clist_use:Nn \l_tmpa_clist {\ ---\ }
\prop_put:NnV \l_karl_some_prop {keyA}\l_tmpa_clist
\par

\clist_set:Nn \l_tmpa_clist {u,v,w,x,y,z}
\clist_use:Nn \l_tmpa_clist {\ ---\ }
\prop_put:NnV \l_karl_some_prop {keyB}\l_tmpa_clist
\par


\prop_map_inline:Nn \l_karl_some_prop 
 { 
   Key\ #1; \ 
   Values\ list:\  \clist_use:nn {#2} {\ ---\ } 
   \par 
 } 

\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}
```

[image]